Audit Logon Failure
An account failed to log on.
Subject:
Security ID:        NULL SID
Account Name:        -
Account Domain:        -
Logon ID:        0x0
Logon Type:            3
Account For Which Logon Failed:
Security ID:        NULL SID
Account Name:        NJV514724$
Account Domain:        CORP.COM
Failure Information:
Failure Reason:        The user has not been granted the requested logon type at this machine.
Status:            0xC000015B
Sub Status:        0x0
Process Information:
Caller Process ID:    0x0
Caller Process Name:    -
Network Information:
Workstation Name:    -
Source Network Address:    10.84.33.193
Source Port:        58570
Detailed Authentication Information:
Logon Process:        Kerberos
Authentication Package:    Kerberos
Transited Services:    -
Package Name (NTLM only):    -
Key Length:        0
This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.
The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.
The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).
The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.
The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.
The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
- Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
- Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
- Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
This is the error that we are getting in the MBAM server, where the endpoints couldn't submit the keys to server, Can anybody help me out to mitigate this.
A Solution for this error
